# Iterate and terminate in java 8 loop

Tags: java-8, iteration, java-stream

Iterate in forEach loop/stream to check for non-null value and return the first non-null value of the item.

`List<Box> boxes;`
`// Each box has List<Items>`
`//Each item has  a value`

Need to iterate through boxes and in each box find the non-null items which has not null value.

Comment: tried using a `for` loop, its worth sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this code:

```
items = boxes.stream()
            .filter(box -> box.items!= null) // check for not null-items 
            .flatMap(box -> box.items.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // check for not null item
                    .filter(item -> item.value != null)) // check for not null value
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of filter and flatMap.
The steps you go through are

1. Filter away null boxes and boxes with no items field
2. Get a list of all items for all boxes using `flatMap`
3. Filter away all null-items

The code looks as follows:

```
List<Item> presentItems = boxes.stream()
    .filter(b -> b != null && b.getItems() != null)
    .flatMap(Box::getItems)
    .filter(i -> i != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On a different note, I would advise you to not keep null entries in your lists if you can avoid it, it'll make your life a lot easier.